# custom events in child userControls c# .net or Child to Parent Communication in UserControls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

Okay here is the scenario:

I have a parent "SalesUC" UserControl which contains a "itemDetailsUC" UserControl, as well as a status label. (plz see sample below)

**What I want:**
If there occurs any exception in itemDetailsUC, it should be able to communicate the exception text to parent control (i.e. SalesUC). *Remember:* the "ItemDetailsUC" is also used in other controls that may or may not have status label.

any suggestions, answers... please.

*Framework: .net 3.0/3.5 Language: c# Domain: Windows Application, WinForms, etc.*

[Sample ScreenShot](http://tinypic.com/r/149qtfn/6)

regards.

Answer (score 1):

Could be several ways,

1. Throw an exception and catch where it is necessary to process.
2. Use custom [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx); here is an [example](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/04/15/events.html).
3. Use [generic event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182178%28VS.80%29.aspx); see the example.